# Android (mono) circle not a circle

Tags: android, canvas

I'm porting an application to android, or mono for android to be exact, and have found that `canvas.DrawCircle` (or DrawArc or DrawOval) do not actually draw true circles. At points around the circle, at multiples of 1/8 revolution, the drawn circle extends beyond the true radius of the circle.

I cannot post images, thanks very much, so here's a link to the actual image.

[link to screen shot demonstrating problem](http://paul.dev.onpix.com/Screenshot.png)

The screenshot shows a circle. The green dots with green lines through them are points drawn at certain angles around the circle origin using the following.

```
            for (float i = 0; i < 360; i += 11.25F)
            {
                float x = circleOriginX + (float)Math.Cos(i * Math.PI / 180F) * circleRadius;
                float y = circleOriginY + (float)Math.Sin(i * Math.PI / 180F) * circleRadius;

                canvas.DrawLine(x, 0, x, viewH, p);
                canvas.DrawLine(0, y, viewW, y, p);
                canvas.DrawCircle(x, y, 2, p);
            }
```

The problem is that I really, really need the circle to be a circle.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can draw a true circle?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081847/how-do-i-offset-a-sector-of-circle-from-its-origin-based-on-the-current-angle

Comment: Sorry, but that does not relate to my problem. I can find any point on the circle. The problem is that certain points that should be on the circle do not lie on the circle. The circle raduis is not constant, as it should be.

Comment: Answer from google...  "Circles are not drawn as perfect circles but as 8 cubic curves"